# Como fazer funcionar o syntax highlighting no Wysiwig Froala?

Tags: wysiwyg

Tenho uma estrutura:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Descrição</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Somente informações verídicas e que possam ser comprovadas, sem
                especulações.
            </small>
        </div>
```

Ao qual é a textarea de descrição/detalhes da notícia.Adicionei algumas dependências JavaScript e CSS:

```
<link href="assets/css/froala_style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/froala_editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

e

```
<script src="assets/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/froala_lang.js"></script> //linguagem em pt-br
```

E agora quero fazer o botão exibição de código https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor que é o botão code view do link mostrado. **Como posso fazer isso?**

Também tentei adicionar:

```
<link href="assets/css/editor-plugins/code_view.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/editor-plugins/code_mirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

e

```
<script src="assets/js/editor-plugins/code_beautifier.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/editor-plugins/code_view.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/editor-plugins/code_mirror.min.js"></script>
```

Ele até mostra o código mas não está destacando nada. Tem algum outro requisito? Podem me ajudar por favor?

Obs: Não quero inserir o froala_editor.pkgd.min.js pois carrega tudo. E não vou usar e nem quero carregar o que não vou usar.